# MacBook not letting me log out of Guest Account

Tags: macos, guest-account

I'm using my brother's new MacBook and it's not letting me log out of the guest account. The only options I see are Restart and Shut Down. How can I log out of the guest account?

Comment: What happens if you just try pressing Shift+Command+Q?

Comment: If you can open Terminal, try typing `sudo killall WindowServer` to kill WindowServer and force log out all graphical users.

Comment: @CyberSkull I don't know of any *guest account* entitled to `sudo`. That would render any security measure useless!

Comment: @klanomath it's been a long time since I used guest, but as I recall it did have Terminal access.

Comment: @CyberSkull But you can't `sudo` with the guest account. In the default OS X setup only members of the admin group can `sudo`.

Comment: @klanomath I could have sworn that `sudo` could prompt for a username? Or am I conflating it with `su`?

Comment: @CyberSkull `sudo` as well as `su` can prompt for a username but the username has to be enabled in the /etc/sudoers file for the former or in /etc/pam.d/su by group membership for the latter to successfully switch to root/admin.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not positive that your bro has Guest Account access set up, OS X introduced a new feature related to 'Find My Mac' that creates a sandboxed fake *Guest Account* in order to make it easier to recover your mac in case it gets stolen, luring the thief to go and connect to some random Wi-Fi with the guest account.

Maybe that's what's going on, you could easily restart and login to any account you like though.